# Renderer has not been properly enabled for the frontend that I´m using

Tags: python, graphics, altair, vega-lite

Sorry this could be a easy doubt but I´m new using python and making code and...

I'm having trouble displaying the following graphs:

The message error is the following :

<VegaLite 4 object>

If you see this message, it means the renderer has not been properly enabled
for the frontend that you are using.

My Jupyterlab version is : 3.2.1

This displays the current version of the extension installed on my syste but I don´t get it

(base) C:\Users\Dell> jupyter labextension list "@jupyterlab/vega4-extension"
JupyterLab v3.2.1
C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\share\jupyter\labextensions
@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v3.0.0 enabled ok (python, jupyterlab_widgets)

To update and make compatible both of them. Do I have to use the following comand?
What should I put in the bold part?

jupyter labextension update **"@jupyterlab/vega4-extension"**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bc48.png)

I already install all of them

pip install -U altair
pip install -U vega
pip install -U vega_datasets

And I even install Node.js and npm

Comment: I want to visualize some graphs but my Jupyterlab version is not compatible with altair and vega-lite and I already try to update my Jupyterlab version but I couldn´t

Comment: Could you edit your code/errors into code blocks?

Comment: Please include the full code you are trying to run as a [mre], e.g. using one of the examples from the gallery (they should all run wihtout any extensions in jupyterlab as long as you are not actively changing the renderers)